# "multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict" when importing from llama_index

Tags: indexing, llama

I've just installed fresh environment. I try to run llama_index example but I get an error already just when importing VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader from llama_index.
Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

llama_index Verison 0.8.42 (tested also with previous version)

Try to eun simple example from tutorial